# ESP8266 Serial dont work if declare pinMode

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp8266

I was trying to make a code for my project. The serial works as it is without declaring  pinMode(r, OUTPUT);, but once I write it in the serial stop working. The board I am using is a esp8266 by nodeMCU. I am using arduino IDE I don't know why this happens. below is my full code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

int BAT= A0; 
int order = 2;
const int r = 1;
const int g = 2;
const int b = 3;


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //char buf[100];
  
  pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(r, LOW); // turn the LED on
  digitalWrite(g, LOW); // turn the LED on
  digitalWrite(b, LOW); // turn the LED on
  
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  double reading = 0.0;
  reading=analogRead(BAT);         //Read analog Voltage
  delay(5);
  float voltage= (reading * (3.3 / 1023.0))*1000;//-64
  double ppm = 0;
  ppm=(-0.00235465)*voltage+402.586;
 // ppm = (((RawHigh - RawLow) * ReferenceRange) / RawRange) + ReferenceLow;
  Serial.print("mv = ");
  Serial.println(voltage);
  Serial.print("concentration = ");
  Serial.println(ppm);
  //delay(750);
  /*
  if(voltage>=200&&voltage<=300){
    digitalWrite(r, HIGH); // turn the LED on
  }else if(voltage>=100&&voltage<=200){
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH); // turn the LED on
  }else if(voltage>=100&&voltage<=0){
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH); // turn the LED on
  }else{
    digitalWrite(r, LOW); // turn the LED on
    digitalWrite(g, LOW); // turn the LED on
    digitalWrite(b, LOW); // turn the LED on
  }
  */
}
```

This code works if I take out the pinMode codes. I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: use `const int r = D1;` D1 is not 1 and Serial is on 1 and 3

Comment: Why have you tagged the both C and C++? Can't you decide which programming language you use?